# Tensorflow: share value for two different variables within same operation

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have been experimenting with TensorFlow (TF) lately and I came across this problem: say I want to compute the value and the gradient of the function

[image: f(x) = \sum_{ijk} x_i x_j x_k]

where the x's are indexed differently but all refer to the same vector [image: bold x] and the J's are random constants (in physics this is a spin glass model). The gradient wrt [image: x_k] is then simply

[image: grad_k(x) = sum_ij x_i*x_j]

hence `f` sums over N^3 terms and `gradf` sums N times over N^2 terms. I have implemented `f` by generating all the terms of the sum as a rank 3 tensor and sum-reducing over all the entries. Then to differentiate I apply

```py
tf.gradients(f, xk)[0]
```

where f is the loss function and xk a variable. Here's a MWE where assume all J's to be 1

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

#first I define the variable                                                                                                                                                                  
n=10 #size of x                                                                                                                                                                               
x1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([n], dtype='float64'))
x2 = tf.placeholder(tf.float64, shape=[n])

#here I define the cost function                                                                                                                                                              
f_tensor = tf.mul(tf.mul(tf.reshape(x1, [n]),
                         tf.reshape(x2, [n,1])),
                  tf.reshape(x2, [n,1,1]))
f = tf.reduce_sum(f_tensor)

session = tf.Session()
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
session.run(init)

#run on test array                                                                                                                                                                            
xtest = np.ones(n)
res = session.run([f, tf.gradients(f, x1)[0]],
                  feed_dict={x1 : xtest,
                             x2 : xtest})

assert res[0] == 1000
assert all(res[1] == np.array([100 for _ in xrange(n)]))
```

I need to call `run` many times independently and I want to reduce the number of variable assignments to just one since x1, x2 refer to the same vector.

Some profiling on a related example for `n=200` (on a GeForce GTX 650) showed that

- cuMemcpyDtoHAsync takes 63% of the time
- cuMemcpyHtoDAsync 18% and
- cuEventRecord 18%.

(results are similar for this mwe)

Hence assignment is the most expensive operation when performing the computation on GPUs. Obviously the overhead gets worse for increasing `n`, hence partially neutralising the benefit of using GPUs.

Any suggestion on how I could be able to do reduce overhead by transferring x only once?

Also any other suggestion on how to reduce any other overhead would be immensely appreciated.

### EDIT

To show the problem in action I'll follow the suggestion by *mrry*.
If I were to replace all instances of x2 with x1 then the MWE would look like this

```py
#first I define the variable                                                                                                                                                                  
n=10 #size of x                                                                                                                                                                               
x1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([n], dtype='float64'))

#here I define the cost function                                                                                                                                                              
f_tensor = tf.mul(tf.mul(tf.reshape(x1, [n]),
                         tf.reshape(x1, [n,1])),
                  tf.reshape(x1, [n,1,1]))
f = tf.reduce_sum(f_tensor)

session = tf.Session()
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
session.run(init)

#run on test array                                                                                                                                                                            
xtest = np.ones(n)
session.run(x1.assign(xtest))
res = session.run([f, tf.gradients(f, x1)[0]])

assert res[0] == 1000
for g in res[1]:
    assert g == 100
```

and the second assertion would fail because each entry for the gradient would be 300 instead of 100, as it should be. The reason is that while xi, xj, xk all refer to the same vector, they are symbolically distinct: replacing all x with the same variable would result in the derivative of x^3, which is 3*x^2, hence the result of the second MWE.

P.S. I have also explicitly assigned x1 for clarity

Comment: If you always feed the same vector for `x1` and `x2`, do you need to define two separate tensors? For example, if you deleted the definition of `x2` and replaced all references to `x2` with `x1`, I think your program would have the same semantics.

Comment: if you try you'll see that the second assert fails. That is because the derivative would be incorrect in that case, the reason being that tf will think that it's taking the derivative of x^3

Comment: This code seems to work for me: https://gist.github.com/mrry/b8f903c8a276f3ed6ebe . Perhaps there is some diference between the code here and the real code that you're running?

Comment: the mwe works, my point is that I want to avoid doing feed_dict={x1 : xtest, x2 : xtest} and replace it with a single assignment. If I replace all x2 with x1 then the second assert fails for the reason I give above. To me it seems unnecessary copying from the host to the device twice given that x1 and x2 are really the same thing, the only reason why they have different names is for the derivative to work out, since symbolically they are distinct.

Comment: Can you update the MWE to demonstrate how your real program fails when you apply my suggested change? I think we might be using the word "assignment" differently. (In addition, without a variable assignment (i.e. `x1.assign(…)`), it's not clear why there's a `tf.Variable` in the program.)

Comment: ok, I'll do the edit. In the meantime: x1 is a variable because I take a derivative wrt it, while I don't take a derivative wrt x2, hence they are logically distinct. I could assign x1 explicitely each time and set x2 using feed_dict. Note, however, that f I wanted to minimize the loss function using say `GradientDescentOptimize` it would not work because for that to work I would have to update both x1 and x2 in the same why, but only take the derivative wrt x1 viz. we are back to the initial issue.

Comment: I have edited the MWE as requested

Comment: Ah, there seems to be a problem with the assertion in the first version of the code: `assert array1.all() == array2.all()` should be `assert all(array1 == array2)`, which reveals the failure when naively substituting x1 for x2.

Comment: yes, I should fix that, I fixed it in the second example though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve your desired outcome is to use the [`tf.stop_gradient()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/train.html#stop_gradient) op to make an efficient copy of the variable `x1` without it contributing to the gradient:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

# First define the variable.
n = 10 # size of x                                                                                                                                                                               
x1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([n], dtype=tf.float64))
x2 = tf.stop_gradient(x1)

# Now define the cost function                                                                                                                                                              
f_tensor = tf.mul(tf.mul(tf.reshape(x1, [n]),
                         tf.reshape(x2, [n,1])),
                  tf.reshape(x2, [n,1,1]))
f = tf.reduce_sum(f_tensor)

session = tf.Session()
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
session.run(init)

# Run on test array                                                                                                                                                                            
xtest = np.ones(n)
res = session.run([f, tf.gradients(f, x1)[0]],
                  feed_dict={x1 : xtest})

assert res[0] == 1000
for g in res[1]:
    assert g == 100
```

Comment: amazing, this is it!

Comment: a related question if I may: if I now change f to
`f = tf.reduce_sum(tf.mul(J, f_tensor))`
where J is a rank 3 tensor declared as a variable with the same shape as f_tensor. Will J be copied back to the host every time session.run is called? because I am still observing that cuMemcpyDtoHAsync is 64% of the total time. Is there an efficient way to put J on the gpu and keep it there until the session is closed?

Comment: If `J` is a variable assigned to the GPU device, it won't be copied back to the host when you call `session.run()` (unless you add it to the list of fetch arguments). How long is your computation taking overall? It's possible that the time spent copying back to host includes the time to compute the result, because everything executes asynchronously (posts kernels to the GPU stream) apart from the final copy back, which must block.

Comment: J is not fetched, it's just like `x1` (not in shape) except that I do not re-assign it every time that I call `session.run()`, so yes it should be copied to the GPU when calling `init = tf.initialize_all_variables(); session.run(init)`. On a GeForce GTX 650, for `n=200` and `ncalls=100` evaluations, the computation takes 20s. Sometimes at the end it also complains about `Raising pool_size_limit_ from 100 to 110`, while it does not when doing ncalls=10. Not sure what that is about.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't comment above (not enough reputation), but note that the analytical gradient should be

$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_k} = \sum_{ij} J_{ijk} x_i x_j + \sum_{ij} J_{ikj} x_i x_j + \sum_{ij} J_{kij} x_i x_j.
$$

Comment: from the very source :) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1522138/derivative-of-kronecker-product

Comment: I was making the exact same mistake :)